# Can sub-15 rep users flag their own content?

Tags: discussion, flagging, reputation

I wondered whether it was possible for a user without flagging privileges to cast flags on their own posts, like how users can delete their own posts.

The reason being some people accidentally post on ELU, without knowing about ELL/Linguistics/Writing. Some questions are reasonable, but just better suited elsewhere. I think it would be beneficial for users to take ownership of their things, rather have the Big Scary Users move it without them wanting it.

But that's by-the-by; what I'm asking is whether it is possible on this site - there is an answer on the [StackExchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228288/should-1-reputation-users-be-able-to-flag-their-own-posts) which says:

> So I'd suggest to evaluate this on a per-site basis. I'd leave this ability enabled for most sites, but it might be rather useful to disable it for high-traffic sites like SO where it causes more problems than it solves.

So is this possible? If not, should it be?

Comment: If users don't know about ELL/Linguistics/Writing, how would they know that they should flag for migration?

Comment: I’m too lazy to do it, but the fastest and most definitive way to check would be to log out, create a brand new account, log in, post, and try to flag.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I could leave a comment and say _'Welcome to ELU, this is a good question, but this is probably the wrong place for it. We have a sister site all about linguistics, so if you flag it for a moderator's attention, they can move it.'_

Comment: @AndrewLeach the difference being suddenly having your question moved around, and actually caring and looking at the linguistics site, etc

Comment: @DanBron I'm too lazy too, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Yes they can](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/514486/testing-for-a-meta-question).

A one-rep user can flag the following:

> **I am flagging to report this question as...**
>
> - should be closed...
>   *This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about English language and usage as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.*
> - a duplicate...
>   *This question has been asked before and already has an answer.*
> - in need of moderator intervention
>   *A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!*